# How to stationarise a univariate time series in R when auto.arima gives a model to fit that doesn't stationarise it?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, identifiability, univariate

I am currently working on a univariate time series that I try to modelize (following the Box-Jenkins methodology, I try to identify the model before I estimate it, using correlograms, in order to later validate it by running PP, ADF tests and so on, and finally, to make previsions). Yet I have trouble to modelize it in a stationary framework. Here is my code :

```
 auto.arima(log_prod_periode_1) # ARIMA(2,1,2)(2,1,1)[12] 
 library(lmtest) # Fit the ARIMA model
 spe <- arima(log_prod_periode_1, order=c(2,1,2), seasonal=list(order=c(2,1,1), 
 period=12))
 coeftest(spe) # AR(2), MA(2) et SMA(1) have significant coefficients
 acf(spe$residuals,lag.max=36)
```

I get the [image: following graph], which indicates that the model fitted isn't sufficient to stationarize my series which is in logarithm (I have already transformed it as the AIC and BIC were lower when i fitted auto.arima to the time series in log than when I fitted it to the initial time series).

Could anyone indicate how I could solve this problem ?
Here is the structure of my dataset :

Comment: well, there is still a significant coeff at lag 3, and R doesn't allow the fitting of a specific MA term at lag 3 when estimating a model using the arima function... I have exposed my issue in more details here : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/615707/what-r-function-can-be-used-to-fit-an-additional-ma-term-at-lag-3-to-my-arima-mo