# what R function can be used to fit an additional MA term at lag 3 to my ARIMA model?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, univariate

I want to fit an ARIMA(1,1,0)(0,1,1)[12] with drift, with an additionnal MA at lag 3 as when I have fitted an ARIMA(1,1,0)(0,1,1)[12] with drift model, I have seen there was still autocorrelation in my residuals at lag 3. Therefore I am trying to add an additional MA or AR term at lag 3. However, the arima function in R does not allow me to do this in a straightforward manner. Indeed, I have tried the following, without success :

```
 # set initial values 
 init <- rep(NA, 4)

 # specify that you want an AR(1) term, an MA(1) term at lag 12, 
 # an MA(1) term at lag 3, and a constant (drift)

 init[c(1, 2, 3, 4)] <- c(0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0)
 eq1cbis <- arima(prod_periode_1, order=c(1,1,0), seasonal=c(0,1,1), fixed=init, 
 include.mean=T)
 eq1cbis
```

The init vector is defined as init <- rep(NA, 4). Then, initial estimates for these parameters are set using:
init[c(1, 2, 3, 4)] <- c(0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0)
This sets initial estimates for the AR(1) term, seasonal MA(1) term, additional MA(1) term at lag 3, and the drift respectively. These are just initial estimates for the optimization
routine used to fit the ARIMA model. The actual estimates of these parameters after the model is fitted may be different (setting initial estimates can sometimes help the optimization routine converge to a solution, especially in complex models, which is not the case here though). If we put NA for an element in the init vector, it means we are asking the arima() function to estimate this parameter. If we put a numeric value, we are asking the function to fix the parameter at this value. In my case, I'm asking the function to estimate all parameters because I haven't set any of the elements in the init vector to a numeric value.

However, this does not work as I get the following message of error from R :

```
 Error in arima(prod_periode_1, order = c(1, 1, 0), seasonal = c(0, 1,  : 
    longueur de 'fixed' incorrecte
```

This is because the ARIMA(1,1,0)(0,1,1)[12] model with drift, as specified by order=c(1,1,0) and seasonal=c(0,1,1), only has three parameters: one for the AR(1) term, one for the seasonal MA(1) term, and one for the drift (or mean). This is why I'm getting an error when I try to pass a fixed vector of length 4.

So it seems the arima() function in R doesn't allow adding a specific MA term at a certain lag in a straightforward manner, and neither does the Arima() function from package forecast. The standard ARIMA model only has parameters for the p most recent AR terms and the q most recent MA terms. If I want an MA term at lag 3 specifically, I would have to specify order=c(1,1,3) for an ARIMA(1,1,3) model, but this model would also include MA terms at lags 1 and 2, which isn't what I want...

How could I fit the model I want on R ?

Here is the structure of my dataset for reproducibility :

```
 structure(c(22951.429, 21465.026, 19334.531, 19319.365, 19923.664, 
 21275.248), tsp = c(1981, 1981.41666666667, 12), class = "ts")
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Please explain how this plot indicates your series doesn't look sufficiently stationary.  To my eye, that ACF is *perfectly consistent with* a completely random series of *iid* values.

Comment: Please think what "significant" means.  (1) By default (in this software), the procedure will on average indicate one in every 20 (100 - 95%) lags is "significant" when the data have no serial correlations. Only one in your 30 lags could be considered "significant." (2) This is an approximate procedure anyway.  With those important caveats in mind, you have no issue at all.  Please don't post an update of your question--we ask you to *edit the existing one* when you want to provide more particulars.  Unfortunately, in this case you have omitted the crucial information, which is your ACF plot!

Comment: That plot, btw, is still available in your previous post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/615457.

Comment: I see your point, but was wondering whether it is possible on R to fit an additional MA at lag 3... because I would really like my residuals to be perfectly white noise

Comment: You have provided no evidence that they are *not* white noise.  If you make your model more complex, you will likely *overfit* the data and make the model worse, not better.